# Php questionnaire with input box

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to write a script that captures the name & email address of participants into a plain text file and also displays the name/textbox contents before/above the answers after pressing the submission button. am new to PHP so am a little lost. below is my code :

```
<?php 




   $Questions = array(
    1 => array(
        'Question' => '1. Do you have the signage displayed in the facility? ',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'A. There is a signage displayed',
            'B' => 'B. There is a signage but this is not displayed',
            'C' => 'C. There is no signage',
            'D' => 'D. Not Applicable'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
    ), 

     2 => array(
        'Question' => '2. Does your signage provide all needed information?',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'A. Yes it does',
            'B' => 'B. Some part of it',
            'C' => 'C. Not at all.',
            'D' => 'D. Not Applicable'

        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
    )
); 

    if (isset($_POST['answers'])){
        $Answers = $_POST['answers']; // Get submitted answers.

        // Now this is fun, automated question checking! ;)

        foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){
            // Echo the question
            echo $Value['Question'].'<br />';




            if ($Answers[$QuestionNo] != $Value['CorrectAnswer']){

                 echo 'You answered: <span style="color: red;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'</span><br>'; // Replace style with a class
                 echo 'The Correct answer: <span style="color: green;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']].'</span>';
            } else {
                echo 'The Correct answer is : <span style="color: green;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'</span><br>'; // Replace style with a class
                echo 'You got it correct: <span style="color: green;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'</span>'; 

                //$counter++;

            }

            echo '<br /><hr>'; 
                                    if ($counter='') 
                                    { 
                                    $counter='0';
                                    $results = "Your score: $counter/2"; 
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    { 
                                    $results = "Your score: $counter/2"; 
                                    }
                }                           echo $results;
    } else {  
    ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="quiz">

            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>






        <?php foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>

            <h3><?php echo $Value['Question']; ?></h3>
            <?php 
              echo '$name' .'<br />';

                foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){ 
                $Label = 'question-'.$QuestionNo.'-answers-'.$Letter;
            ?>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $QuestionNo; ?>]" id="<?php echo $Label; ?>" value="<?php echo $Letter; ?>" />
                <label for="<?php echo $Label; ?>"><?php echo $Letter; ?>) <?php echo $Answer; ?> </label>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
        <br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit And View Suggestions Now" />
        </form>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: i want the code to "echo" out the name and email together with the answers when a visitor fills in the input form and the questions.

Comment: That still isn't a question. You are stating what you want to do but haven't described what you have attempted, and what problem(s) you have encountered.

Comment: ok. I have managed to get a questionnaire and the correct answers in an array displaying properly.What I'm attempting to do is to, add input form to display the name of the student answering the question. Can you help me "edit" the code to echo the name and email as well as the answers.

Comment: No, this is not a "fill in the blanks for me" place. It is for asking a question and showing what you have attempted.

Comment: Please find above, my attempted code. I need help because am new and stuck. am not asking for you to fill in the blank for me. am asking for help with editing what am gettting wrong that is not echoing the input fields.thanks

Comment: What happens, and doesn't happen, with your code? Whereabouts? Are there errors? Then post the error details. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At this point you would be better off starting over to provide a new, clear, question.